# display the same side side by slde as two row

Tags: html, styles

i have used a code and is described below. I need to display the contents in div side by side rather than displaying down. i cant change the div since the div is actually repeating by time. In my code the the first div that i wrote is repeating so i cant change the div any change in the first div reflect in other too. Please give a solution for this. Thank you in advance.

```
<style>
  .your_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.wfte_invoice-main {
  color: #73879c;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
}
</style>

    <div class="your_container">
      <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
        2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
      </p>
     
    </div>
      <div class="your_container">
      <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
        2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
      </p>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use float property which is used for positioning the content left and right on the screen.

```css
.your_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}

.wfte_invoice-main {
  color: #73879c;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="your_container">
      <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
        2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
      </p>
     
    </div>
      <div class="your_container">
      <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
        2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
      </p>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Place a wrapper around `your_container` and style to the wrapper as `display: flex`.

css:

```
.main-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.your_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%; /* width of the container */
    padding: 0 15px; /* to add spaces  between container */
}

.wfte_invoice-main {
    color: #73879c;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="your_container">
        <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
            2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
        </p>

    </div>
    <div class="your_container">
        <p class="wfte_invoice-main">
            2 any street basingstoke, United Kingdom, SP49 4ED
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```